# Sending form data to specific email address using react-form

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs

I am using [React Form](https://react-form.js.org/#/) to create a contact form in a basic React landing page and I want, when the user presses submit, the data to be sent to a specific email address (e.g. info@info.com). I am soory if this is a rookie question but I cannot seem to find the answer!

```
//the state  
constructor(props) {
super(props);
//this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
this.state = {};
```

}

```
//the form
<Form onSubmit={submittedValues => this.setState( { submittedValues } )}>
        { formApi => (
          <form onSubmit={formApi.submitForm} id="form2">
            <label htmlFor="firstName">First name</label>
            <Text field="firstName" id="firstName" />
            <label htmlFor="lastName">Last name</label>
            <Text field="lastName" id="lastName" />
            <label htmlFor="email">Email"</label>
            <Text field="email" id="email" />
            <label htmlFor="subject">Subject</label>
            <Text field="subject" id="subject" />
            <label htmlFor="message">Message</label>
            <TextArea field="message" id="message" />
            <button type="submit" className="mb-4 btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </form>
        )}
      </Form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by doing following steps:

1. First of all you need a script on backend (server side) which would send an email whatever data you pass it.
2. Second, you need to send an Ajax Request to that script on server side and pass all the data you need to send through Email.

If you are using PHP on server side you can use **PHP's mail function** or you can use any library of your choice.